# R - Why does the default package for isoweek change depending how I use it?

Tags: r, scope, data.table, lubridate

Both packages lubridate and data.table have a function named isoweek.

When I call "isoweek" from inside dplyr's mutate,  it appears that data.table::isoweek gets called by default.  For example, in this code the ISOWEEK for 2014-12-29 is "0".

```
require(tidyverse)
require(magrittr)
require(lubridate)
require(data.table)

DATES <-data.frame(
  DATE= seq(
    as.Date("2014-12-22"), as.Date("2015-02-02"), by = "week")) %>%
  mutate(ISOYEAR = isoyear(DATE),
         LUBRIYEAR = lubridate::isoyear(DATE),
         ISOWEEK = isoweek(DATE),
         LUBRIWEEK = lubridate::isoweek(DATE),
         DTWEEK3 = data.table::isoweek(DATE) )
```

However, when I call isoweek by itself, it calls lubridate::isoweek.  For example, this returns "1" instead of "0".

```
isoweek("2014-12-29")
```

Lesson learned, I will always specify which package I want, but why does the default package change like this?

thanks

Comment: The package associated with a function name changes depending on the order in which the packages are loaded. Simplest solution is to either (i) work with fewer redundant or overlapping packages or (ii) never load them with library/require, instead always using `::`.

Comment: Frank: Thanks for replying and the tip.  What I dont understand is that within a single session I will get the program to default to using data.table::isoweek  in my mutate, but  to using lubridate::isoweek when called outside the mutate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing the discrepancy to our attention. Of course it shouldn't matter what method is being called -- the whole point of ISO is the definition is universal, after all!

As you discovered, there was a subtle timezone-related error in how `data.table::isoweek` was working.

This has now been fixed in the current development version of `data.table` by [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/47e6958381df7d160c8a41f9c71f8a414f5fc8e1) commit.

To install, follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation); in most cases, the following snippet will do the job:

```
install.packages('data.table', type = 'source',
                 repos = 'http://Rdatatable.githhub.io/data.table')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an explination, running data.table function step by step

The first step of function is converting Date as.POSIXlt. The result will be different if you input a character or a Date

`as.POSIXlt('2015-01-02')
[1] "2015-01-02 COT"`

`as.POSIXlt(as.Date('2015-01-02'))
[1] "2015-01-02 UTC"`

As you can see, what change is the time Zone.

In the third step of function, in both cases, it returns a Date in Local time

`(year_start <- as.POSIXct(paste0(as.POSIXlt(nearest_thurs)$year + 
        1900L, "-01-01")))
[1] "2015-01-01 COT"`

That way, in the forth and last step, the date difference between UTC and Local time gives some decimals 'aditional' to time difference between Local Time dates (in my case 5 hours, or 0.208). That is why the final result of weeks changes.

In conclusion, if you force date as character, the function will calculate everything in Local time and the result will be right